# in Navigatin Drawer with Swipe Tabs how to make and set fragments for each tab inside

Tags: android, android-fragments, tabs

Hello I amtrying to develop app with Navigation Drawer and Swipe Tabs and I made like this picture but here all tabs are located in one fragment can I divide and make fragment to each other tab(item 1,item 2...) inside can you help me make fragment to ech other(item 1,item 2...) and how and where add thanks  [image]

Code:

```
  import android.os.Bundle;
  import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
  import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
  import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
  import android.view.LayoutInflater;
  import android.view.View;
  import android.view.ViewGroup;
  import android.widget.TextView;


 public class ScreenOne extends Fragment {

private SlidingTabLayout mSlidingTabLayout;
private ViewPager mViewPager;

public ScreenOne() {
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.screen_one, container, false);

    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Get the ViewPager and set it's PagerAdapter so that it can display items
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(new SamplePagerAdapter());

    // Give the SlidingTabLayout the ViewPager, this must be 
    // done AFTER the ViewPager has had it's PagerAdapter set.
    mSlidingTabLayout = (SlidingTabLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.sliding_tabs);
    mSlidingTabLayout.setViewPager(mViewPager);
}

// Adapter
class SamplePagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    /**
     * Return the number of pages to display
     */
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 10;
    }

    /**
     * Return true if the value returned from is the same object as the View
     * added to the ViewPager.
     */
    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object o) {
        return o == view;
    }

    /**
     * Return the title of the item at position. This is important as what
     * this method returns is what is displayed in the SlidingTabLayout.
     */
    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return "Item " + (position + 1);
    }

    /**
     * Instantiate the View which should be displayed at position. Here we
     * inflate a layout from the apps resources and then change the text
     * view to signify the position.
     */
    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        // Inflate a new layout from our resources
        View view = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.pager_item,
                container, false);
        // Add the newly created View to the ViewPager
        container.addView(view);

        // Retrieve a TextView from the inflated View, and update it's text
        TextView title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.item_title);
        title.setText(String.valueOf(position + 1));

        // Return the View
        return view;
    }

    /**
     * Destroy the item from the ViewPager. In our case this is simply
     * removing the View.
     */
    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        container.removeView((View) object);
    }
 }  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this 
I am trying it as well

http://www.paulusworld.com/technical/android-navigationdrawer-sliding-tabs

Comment: Yes I am sure because its his tutorial and my problem is how to get fragments from each tabs,there all tabs are located in one Fragment

Comment: yup the tutorial is the base and then you can create on fragments and swich on position in the getItem of SectionsPagerAdapter

Comment: @priyankamorisetti the tittle will move as it is associated with the fragment

Comment: @YokaiTheMonster : yup they have moved it out

Comment: @YokaiTheMonster : Anyways now you can start using new things like the  NAVIGATION DRAWER and MATERIAL TABS. Hope it helps

Comment: Yup this is a Good Example see:- https://inducesmile.com/android/add-swipe-tabs-inside-navigation-drawer-in-android/ i'm implemented in my project @SagarDevanga